# Why use diode connected BJT (and not just connect two BJT back-to-back) for current mirror circuit?

Tags: bjt, current-mirror

I have been studying about current mirror circuits using BJTs. The circuit I have is this:

[image]

For the left BJT, it says:

```
IC1 = Io(e^(Vbe1/Vt))
```

This is understandable because it is "diode connected", hence will follow diode equation.

For the right BJT as well, it says:

```
IC2 = Io(e^(Vbe2/Vt))
```

Then they take `log`, and compare Vbe1 = Vbe2 and conclude IC1 = IC2; Iref = Iout.

If the same diode equation is applicable to the right BJT as well, then what is the purpose of making the left one "diode connected"?" Why can't we just remove the wire (shown in green question mark) from the left BJT?

Answer (score 4):

If you were to do what you suggest, there wouldn't be any path for base current into either transistor's base, and you wouldn't get any current in either the input *or* the output side.

> Isn't ideally the base current 0?

Ideally, the base current is zero *and* β is infinite. Since we don't have transistors with infinite β, the base current has to be \$\frac{I_c}{β}\$ instead. The presence of base current is a source of nonideality in the current mirror; it means that the output current won't be exactly equal to the input, even if both transistors are 100% identical in every way.

> what is the advantage of using diode connected BJT if we can use the diode equation in the other BJT as well?

I don't understand this question? How you hook up one transistor has nothing to do with how you model the other one.

Comment: Isn't ideally the base current 0? Another question is what is the advantage of using diode connected BJT if we can use the diode equation in the other BJT as well?

Comment: @Confusedtransistor See my edits.

Comment: Supplement to Hearth's, The mirror makes Iref == Iout by two matching transistors seeing the same base current:<br/> Ib1 == Ib2, Iref = Beta x Ib1, & Iout = Beta x Ib2; Leads to Iref = Iout.

Comment: @jay Not quite; \$I_{ref} = (β+1)·I_{b1}\$, so there's a small difference between \$I_{ref}\$ and \$I_{out}\$. A full explanation would also include the reason why \$I_{b1}=I_{b2}\$, too--LvW would be proud.

Comment: @Hearth Good catch! Agreed about "Beta + 1".

Comment: @Hearth What is LvW? Is it about  = Vbe / Rb?

Comment: Hi Hearth, this is LvW, I really do not know why I should be proud - however, may I ask you why Ib1=Ib2 ? To me, this is a statement without reasoning without mentioning the driving voltage....

Comment: Ha! Nice meeting you LvW. One of my questions has been answered :-).

Comment: @Hearth thanks for the explanation. So we can say that Ic arises because of Ib? If no Ib then no Ic? That is why the diode-connected BJT is needed?

And my previous question was if the same diode eqn can be applied to right BJT (which is not diode connected BJT), then why not use a simple BJT on the left. I guess that can be answered if, like you said, Ib is really necessary for producing Ic (even if completely ideal BJTs).

Comment: @jay LvW is a user of this forum who I mostly know for getting rather upset when people model BJTs as current-controlled devices; this is one of the situations where their preferred voltage-controlled model is necessary.

Comment: @Confusedtransistor Until you reach breakdown or saturation, \$I_C=βI_B\$. No base current means the transistor is turned off.

Comment: @LvW Proud was the wrong word to use there, I think. Not sure what the right one is--the need to consider the voltage in this particular case just reminded me of how you always seem so insistent on using voltage-controlled models for BJTs.

Comment: Hearth, thank you - however, just a small correction: I have no problems to use a BJT MODEL based on a current-controlled device. If it works !  But we should not forget that it is just a model. As we all know, a model will not necessarily reflect always the physical truth.  And the current mirror is a good example where such a model fails. On the other hand, there are no real circuits where the voltage-control model (Ic=f(Vbe)) would fail. Or do you have a counterexample?